# Conditional Dropdown Menus in Wix

Tags: javascript, java, drop-down-menu, velo

First post on here and I'm not particularly technical so please bare with me! I am trying to create multiple conditional dropdowns in the Wix website builder so that the contents of each dropdown is dependent on the selection from the previous one. My database is called 'Products' and the Columns are "Manufacturer", "Model" & "Part". The dropdown menus are called #dropdown 1, #dropdown2 & #dropdown3.

The first dropdown correctly populates from the database however when something is selecting it doesn't populate the second dropdown so I'm not sure if the code is firing or not. My code is below, any help would be much appreciated as I've been struggling with this for days!!

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {
    uniqueDropDown1();
});

function uniqueDropDown1 (){
    wixData.query("Products")
        .limit(1000) 
      .find()
      .then(results => {
           const uniqueTitles = getUniqueTitles(results.items); 
           $w("#dropdown1").options = buildOptions(uniqueTitles); 
      });
  function getUniqueTitles(items) {
        const titlesOnly = items.map(item => item.Manufacturer);
     return [...new Set(titlesOnly)];
    }
    function buildOptions(uniqueList) { 
        return uniqueList.map(curr => {
            return {label:curr, value:curr}; 
        });
    }
 }
 export function dropdown1_change(event) {
 uniqueDropDown2(); 
 $w("#dropdown2").enable();
 function uniqueDropDown2 (){
    wixData.query("Products")
        .contains("Manufacturer", $w("#dropdown1").value)
        .limit(1000) 
      .find()
      .then(results => {
           const uniqueTitles = getUniqueTitles(results.items); 
           $w("#dropdown2").options = buildOptions(uniqueTitles);
      });

  function getUniqueTitles(items) {
        const titlesOnly = items.map(item => item.Manufacturer);
     return [...new Set(titlesOnly)];
    }
    function buildOptions(uniqueList) { 
        return uniqueList.map(curr => {
            return {label:curr, value:curr}; 
        });
    }
}
}

export function dropdown2_change(event) {
    uniqueDropDown3(); 
    $w("#dropdown3").enable();
    function uniqueDropDown3 (){
    wixData.query("Products")
        .contains("Model", $w("#dropdown2").value)
        .limit(1000) 
      .find()
      .then(results => {
           const uniqueTitles = getUniqueTitles(results.items); 
           $w("#dropdown3").options = buildOptions(uniqueTitles); 
      });
}

  function getUniqueTitles(items) {
        const titlesOnly = items.map(item => item.Model);
    return [...new Set(titlesOnly)];
    }
    function buildOptions(uniqueList) { 
        return uniqueList.map(curr => {
            return {label:curr, value:curr}; 
        });
    }
}
```

Many thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 0):

import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {
$w('#dataset_id').onReady(() => {

```
    $w('#dropdown_1_id').onChange(() => {
        search();
    })
    $w('#dropdown_2_id').onChange(() => {
        search();
    })

    function search() {
        let productFilter = wixData.filter();
        let variable_1 = $w("#dropdown_1_id").value;
        let variable_2 = $w("#dropdown_2_id").value;

        if (variable_2) {
            productFilter = productFilter.eq("database_name_variable2", variable_2);
        }
        if (variable_1 && variable_1 !== 'All') {
            productFilter = productFilter.eq("database_name_variable1", variable_1);
        }

        if (variable_2 && variable_2 !== 'All') {
            productFilter = productFilter.eq("database_name_variable2", variable_2);
        }

        $w('#dataset_id').setFilter(productFilter)

    }

});
```

});

Comment: Thanks very much for this Sneha, are you suggesting I replace all my code with the code above? Or does this need to be inserted somewhere? - Sorry I am a total newbie!

Comment: Just replace all code and set all id's and execute

Comment: Thanks for your help Sneha, I have done that but now I am getting "TypeError: undefined is not a function" Error. I also have 3 dropdowns called Manufacturer, Model and Part and the database name is Products. Can you help please?

Comment: have your add this line at the top of your code :
import wixData from 'wix-data';

Comment: Hi, I have amended the code now so the dropdown is firing but it is not populating with the correct values but it is enabling the dropdowns. I have put the new code in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally got this working. The problem was that my OnChange events were not defined to the dropdown. Code below:

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {
    uniqueDropDown1();
});

function uniqueDropDown1 (){
    wixData.query("Products")
        .limit(1000) 
      .find()
      .then(results => {
           const uniqueTitles = getUniqueTitles(results.items); 
           $w("#dropdown1").options = buildOptions(uniqueTitles); 
      });
  function getUniqueTitles(items) {
        const titlesOnly = items.map(item => item.Manufacturer);
     return [...new Set(titlesOnly)];
    }
    function buildOptions(uniqueList) { 
        return uniqueList.map(curr => {
            return {label:curr, value:curr}; 
        });
    }
 }
 export function dropdown1_change(event) {
uniqueDropDown2(); 
 $w("#dropdown2").enable();
function uniqueDropDown2 (){
    wixData.query("Products")
        .contains("Manufacturer", $w("#dropdown1").value)
        .limit(1000) 
      .find()
      .then(results => {
           const uniqueTitles = getUniqueTitles(results.items); 
           $w("#dropdown2").options = buildOptions(uniqueTitles);
      });

  function getUniqueTitles(items) {
        const titlesOnly = items.map(item => item.Model);
     return [...new Set(titlesOnly)];
    }
    function buildOptions(uniqueList) { 
        return uniqueList.map(curr => {
            return {label:curr, value:curr}; 
        });
    }
}
}

export function dropdown2_change(event) {
    uniqueDropDown3(); 
    $w("#dropdown3").enable();
    function uniqueDropDown3 (){
    wixData.query("Products")
        .contains("Model", $w("#dropdown2").value)
        .limit(1000) 
      .find()
      .then(results => {
           const uniqueTitles = getUniqueTitles(results.items); 
           $w("#dropdown3").options = buildOptions(uniqueTitles); 
     });
}

  function getUniqueTitles(items) {
        const titlesOnly = items.map(item => item.Part);
     return [...new Set(titlesOnly)];
    }
    function buildOptions(uniqueList) { 
        return uniqueList.map(curr => {
            return {label:curr, value:curr}; 
        });
    }
}
```